# How to prevent Whitescreen occurence in Kitkat

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I intermittently see nothing but white screen as I lock my Sony Xperia E1 powered by Android Kitkat 4.4.2. Have you any solution, guys? Thank You for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have rooted device**

Go to root > data >system_layout

open background.xml and set backgrounnd as transparent.